# Getting the next item in an array based on the ID of the previous item

Tags: php, arrays, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

**A little background information**

I am using AngularJS as a frontend framework and Laravel for an API for the front end to communicate with.

**The problem**

For this app I have a 'section' which has a next/prev button in the view, when the next is clicked, an API call is made with the current section ID as a parameter. From this I was hoping to get hold of the next or previous item in the array depending on the endpoint I use (which button was clicked).

How would I go about this in PHP/Laravel, is it possible or should I be re thinking about the structure of my app/api?

**What I have now**

So at the moment, I all I have is a 'Section' collection:

`$sections = Section::orderBy('order', 'DESC')->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination)

```
$sections = Section::orderBy('order', 'DESC')->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->paginate(2);
return response()->json($sections );
```

Then you will get something like (I convert into json)

```
{
    "total": 17,
    "per_page": 2,
    "current_page": 1,
    "last_page": 9,
    "next_page_url": "{{URL}}?page=2",
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "from": 1,
    "to": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 40,
            "order":1
        },
        {
            "id": 41,
            "order":2
        },
     ]
 }
```

Now use the url form "next_page_url" or "prev_page_url"

Comment: This might be on to something, can't believe I havn't tried this one out yet. Looking into it now!

Comment: let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Ok, I have implemented this approach and it works perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Plain SQL You can do it in following way to get the next item.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE COLUMN_ID =
    (SELECT min(COLUMN_ID)
     FROM TABLE_NAME
     WHERE COLUMN_ID > REPLACE_PREVIOUS_ID_HERE)
```

In above query, the sub query just finds the very next COLUMN_ID after your previous key and return it to the main query.

Comment: The issue is the ordering, I can't use ID's as sometimes the 'order' column can overwrite this, for example, the user could enter 5 Sections with ID's 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. But the user then decides that they want Section ID 3 to appear on the front end first, so they set the order column to 4. Our new Section array will now be 3, 1, 2, 4, 5.

Comment: @SeriousJelly: You should mention such restrictions upfront in your question.