# Update Laravel pagination in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

Hi Community Fairly new to Laravel and wanted to know how I would update Laravels Pagination in Javascript. If that is at all possible and how to go about it

This is My Route:

```
Route::get('/vehicles/search/{make}/{model}/{type}/{yearf}/{yeart}/{minp}/{maxp}', 'VehiclesController@searchVehicle');
```

My Controller:

```
public function searchVehicle($make,$model,$type,$yearf,$yeart,$minp,$maxp)
{
   $results = Vehicles::where('make', 'LIKE', '%'.$make. '%')->orWhere('model','LIKE', '%'.$model.'%')->paginate(2);

return($results);

}
```

And my JS:

```
var strUrl = vehicle_url + "search/" + vmake + "/" + vmodel + "/" + yearfrom + "/" + yearto + "/" + type + "/" + minprice + "/" + maxprice;
var obj = sendRequest(strUrl);
```

It would be updating my laravel pagination which would be:

```
{{$all->links}}
```

Comment: this my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205086/getting-the-next-item-in-an-array-based-on-the-id-of-the-previous-item/38206522#38206522 that may help you

Comment: @AgeValed Thanks for the swift response. In relation to your solution, I can get the data from the database in JSON what to do after that is the problem.